Tests in Playwright fail due to pop-ups
I'm trying to do a test to press all the buttons on any website. On simple sites the code works, if pop-ups appear the test crashes. What are the options in this situation? Don't judge strictly, I'm a beginner.
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test('get started link', async ({ page }) => {
  
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com/');
    
  await expect(async () => {  
    for (const li of await page.getByRole('button').all())  
    await  li.click();
    
  }).toPass();
  expect (await page.goto('https://www.google.com/'));
});here

Tried page.on dialog and popup. They do not work.
